# How do I remove a certain column from matrices in a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

If I have a cell array containing few matrices in it. Each matrix has different row numbers but same column numbers.

`C{1} = [30x4 double]
 C{2} = [25x4 double] 
 C{3} = [32x4 double] ...etc`

If I want to remove the first and the third columns in each matrix, what should I do?

So the cell array will become:

`new_C{1} = [30x2 double]
new_C{2} = [25x2 double]
new_C{3} = [32x2 double]`

where those two columns in new_C are from the second and the fourth columns in the cell array C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have tried the obvious solution using a `for` loop.
Another way would be using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), combined with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?searchHighlight=logical%20indexing#bq7egb6-1):

```
columns = false(1, 4);
columns([2, 4]) = true;
D = cellfun(@(m)m(:,columns), C, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

first, we build an index vector for the columns. Then we use `cellfun` to apply the indexing to every element in the cell array. We use `'UniformOutput', 0`, because we want to obtain another cell array (and the results of the indexing operation are not scalar).

Comment: Thanks! This works!!
Yeah, I did try a for loop but I was thinking if there's any other more efficient ways to solve it. Sorry, I should have mentioned this.